# Changing Support ActionBarDrawerToggle icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle" and i need to use custom icon for the toggle, and i still get the default toggle icons although i initialized it as following :

```
mNavDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this
               ,mDrawerLayout
               ,R.drawable.menu // <-- My Custom Icon 
               , R.string.str_all) {
            }
```

// Update
So Weird, It works with "android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle" which is deprecated and doesn't work with "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle" which is not deprecated,

Any advice.?!, Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
    `mNavDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);`

Try Replacing the Home as Up Button with Your own image Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    mNavDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this
                   ,mDrawerLayout
                   , R.string.str_all, R.string.closeDrawerDescribtion) {
                }
mNavDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator (R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Comment: The constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity, DrawerLayout, int, int, int) is undefined

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks

Comment: It works with "android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle" which is deprecated and doesn't work with "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle" which is not deprecated

Comment: You need to be using a toolbar